# Powershell Using Expressions in Parameters in the Pipeline: "Move-Item : The given path's format is not supported."

Tags: powershell

I have the following bit of code in a powershell script thats bombing with Move-Item : The given path's format is not supported.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
 $computer = gc env:computername

 write-host "Moving archives `r`n"
 gci -Path $logdir -Recurse -Include *.7z |  ForEach-Object {  
 mi -Path $_.FullName -Destination \\storage\logs\iis\$computer\$_.Directory.Name\ -force -WhatIf
 }
```

Could anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: It would help if you gave the values of: $_.FullName and $_.Directory.Name when it is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks - that also chokes but with a different error: Move-Item : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
At script.ps1:39 char:4
+     mi <<<<  -Path "$($_.FullName)" -Destination "\\storage\logs\iis\$co
mputer\$($_.Directory.Name)\" -force
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\inetpub\logs...u_ex12101908.7z:F
   ileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com
   mands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: $_.FullName = C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12102519.7z (for example)

Comment: In the text you copied and paste in your comment - there is a space in $co mputer - is this the way it is in your code?

Comment: No - thats just an artifact of copying and pasting from the powershell console

Comment: The destination folder didn't exist. I thought -force would create it but apparently not. I had to change my code as follows: gci -Path $logdir -Recurse -Include *.7z |  ForEach-Object {  
 if(!(Test-Path -Path "\\storage\logs\iis\$($computer)\$($_.Directory.Name)\"))
 {
 md "\\storage\logs\iis\$($computer)\$($_.Directory.Name)\"
 }
 else
 {
 mi -Path "$($_.FullName)" -Destination "\\storage\logs\iis\$($computer)\$($_.Directory.Name)\" -force
 }
}

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to use the pipeline object `$_` in an expression for a cmdlet parameter argument, the parameter must first support pipeline binding and second, you must put the argument in a scriptblock e.g.:

```
ls *.txt | mi -Destination {"\\storage\logs\iis\$computer\$($_.Directory.Name)"} -force -WhatIf
```

Comment: I tried this like the following: ls | move-item -Destination ../$($_.Name), why didn't it require a scriptblock (or is it implicitly creating one)?

Comment: @dugas Are you saying it worked without using the scriptblock?  If you think it is working, are you sure it is evaluating $_.Name correctly?